# $ A $ defines an bounded operator on $l^2 (\mathbb{N})$ such that $\|A\| \leq \frac{1+r}{1-r}$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This question was asked in my mid term of Functional Analysis course and I was not able to solve it.

> Question: Let A be an infinite matrix $(a_{ij})_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}$. It is assumed that there exists r<1 such that for every $i,j \in \mathbb{N} : |a_{ij} | \leq r^{|{j-i}|}$. Show that  A defines an bounded operator on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ with $\|A\|\leq \frac{ (1+r) }{1-r}$.

Attempt: I am unable to think how should I apply the condition $|a_{ij}|\leq r^{|j-i|}$ so as to calculate the norm of A and that is why I am not able to make any progress on this question.

Can you please help on how norm should be calculated of this operator?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you write down the definition of the operator whose matrix is $(a_{ij})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix can be represented by the sum $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty A_k$$ where $$(A_k)_{ij}=\begin{cases} a_{ij}&i-j=k\\ 0& i-j\neq k
\end{cases}$$ The entries of the matrix $A_k$ lie on one line parallel to the main diagonal and are bounded above by $r^{|k|}.$ Therefore $\|A_k\|\le r^{|k|}.$ Hence $$\|A\|\le \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \|A_k\|\le \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty r^{|k|}={1+r\over 1-r}$$
The estimate is sharp. Indeed Let $a_{ij}=r^{|i-j|}.$ Then $A$ is the convolution operator with the sequence $\{r^{|n|}\}_{n=\infty}^\infty.$ By the Fourier transform the operator $A$ is unitarily equivalent to the multiplication operator on $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ with the function $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}={1-r^2\over 1-2r\cos \theta +r^2}$$ The norm of this operator is equal to the maximal value of this function, which is attained for $\theta=0$ and is equal ${1+r\over 1-r}.$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the representation as a sum was written by you  ?

Comment: Any infinite matrix $A$ indexed by the integers can be represented as a sum of matrices $A_k$ which equal to $A$ on the line $i-j=k$ and zero if $i-j\neq k.$ For example $A_0$ corresponds to  the main diagonal of $A,$ $A_1$ corresponds to the first line above the main diagonal, etc.